# How to change content of div using jquery or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<a href="/home/" id="one"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#one').

});
</script>
```

How to change anchor tag to `<a href="/home/" id="one"><img src="images/img2.png"/></a>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
$("#one img").prop("src", "images/img2.png");
```

It will change the `src` property of `<img>` element to `"images/img2.png"`.

Comment: Change `prop` to `attr` Read http://api.jquery.com/attr/ and http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @RohanKumar Could you tell me why do I need to change `prop` to `attr`?

Comment: It depends upon the jquery version, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: Are you serious, guys? Use slow `attr` because `prop` is not supported by ancient versions of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#one').on('click',function(e){
       $(this).children('img').attr('src','images/img2.png');
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```